# Magento2 Login Link Redirecting to Homepage

Tags: magento2, admin-login

plz, help me my magento2 login URL is redirecting to the homepage I'm struggling it with from last two days but unable to fix it. any help highly appreciated.

(this is happened after installing stripe and blog module I'm not sure it is an issue or not)

my website speed also becomes very very slow. plz help me for the login link which is very very compulsory at the moment

http://muzikhausberlin.de

Comment: Does it work after disabling or uninstalling stripe and blog module?

Comment: after disabling both now site stopped working

Comment: What is the error ? Check server logs.

Comment: i'm much worried its not working

Comment: nothing in log.. i think problem in htaccess file